# Populating 2 select elements in javascript clears the first one

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I have an array in Javascript that is filled with `<option>` elements. 
I'm looping over this array with the following code:

```
array.forEach(e => {
  selectElement1.appendChild(e);
  selectElement2.appendChild(e);
});
```

This results in only the last selectElement within the forEach loop being populated.

How can I populate both the select elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appending a node with a parent to another node, moves the node to the new parent. To solve this, you can [clone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) the node.

```
var dupNode = node.cloneNode([deep]);
```

**Note:** Since you want the text (a child of the cloned node) to be cloned as well, set the deep clone option to `true`.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3];

array.forEach(e => {
  var el = document.createElement('option');
  el.textContent = e;
  
  var el2 = el.cloneNode(true); // cloning with the deep option

  selectElement1.appendChild(el);
  selectElement2.appendChild(el2);
});
```

```html
<select id="selectElement1"></select>
<select id="selectElement2"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was a bit late, but already had an answer, hope it helps.

---

According to the documentation, the [`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) method.

> Adds a node to the end of the list of children of a specified parent
>   node. If the node already exists it is removed from current parent
>   node, then added to new parent node.
>
> This means that a node can't be in two points of the document
>   simultaneously. So if the node already has a parent, the node is first
>   removed, then appended at the new position. The [`Node.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) can
>   be used to make a copy of the node before appending it under the new
>   parent.

```js
const selects = {
  one: document.getElementById('select1'),
  two: document.getElementById('select2')
};

const OptionFactory = {
  create(text, value) {
    return new Option(text, value);
  }
};

const {
  create
} = OptionFactory;

const options = [create('Option 1', 1), create('Option 2', 2)];

const addOption = (select, option) => {
  select.add(option);
};

options.forEach(option => {
  const clonedOption = option.cloneNode(true);
  addOption(selects.one, option);
  addOption(selects.two, clonedOption);
});
```

```html
<select id="select1"></select>
<select id="select2"></select>
```